# Need help in cypress to read data from excel/csv

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am trying to read the test cases from excel and then pass it to cypress to execute it.

What I want is that my excel will be consist of all sites

```
abc.com, example.com ,xyz.com
```

like 50 to 100 such a sites

and then pass it to cypress and cypress will execute each site for 100 sites.

I tried to this by reading cypress plugins but not so sure on how I can do this. Any guidance will be very helpful

My goal is to run test cases like the site is loading for more than 100 sites

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Cypress [Module API](https://on.cypress.io/module-api) to do this programmatically, by changing the `baseUrl` of the tests each time.

Something like this should work, just as a Node script:

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

const baseUrlList = loadSitesFromExcel()

// create a recursive Promise chain
function runTests(i = 0) {
  if (i == baseUrlList.length) {
    return Promise.resolve()
  }

  return cypress.run({
    config: {
      baseUrl: baseUrlList[i]
    }
  })
  .then((results) => {
    // do something with results, then run next test
    return runTests(i + 1)
  })
}

// begin
runTests()
```